# Hfill right align spills over to next line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

This code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Formulae\hfill(RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT.)
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

I was hoping/expecting that "(RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT)" would all be on the second line (and flushed right). But somehow the third RIGHT falls to the third line.

What should I do to achieve my desired result?

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill}\mbox{ (RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT.)}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That seems to work, thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you write an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is solved in the second comment.